# Interchanging integrals and continuous linear forms in RKHS

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading *Reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces in probability and statistics* by A Berlinet, C Thomas-Agnan.

In Chapter 5 INTEGRATION OF $\mathcal{H}$-VALUED RANDOM VARIABLES they write **One of the most useful result is the possibility of interchanging integrals and continuous linear forms.** however I cannot find an explicit statement on the requirements therefore.

We have the following preliminaries:

- $(E,\mathcal{T})$ a measurable space,
- $\mathcal{M}$ the space of signed measures on $(E,\mathcal{T})$,
- $\mathcal{P}$ the set of probability measures on $(E,\mathcal{T})$,
- $K$ a real reproducing kernel on $E\times E$,
- $\mathcal{H}$ the (separable) reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS) with kernel $K$,
- $\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{H}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of  $\mathcal{H}$

Page 210:

> If $K$ is bounded and measurable then 
>   \begin{align}
> (E,\mathcal{T},\mu) &\to (\mathcal{H},\mathcal{B}_\mathcal{H})\\
> x & \mapsto K(.,x)
> \end{align}
>   is strongly (Bochner) integrable for all $\mu$ in $\mathcal{M}$ and we can define a mapping
>   \begin{align}
> I\colon \mathcal{M} &\to \mathcal{H}\\
> \mu &\mapsto I_\mu = \int K(.,x) d\mu(x)
> \end{align}

The authors write earlier on page 188 (boundness on $K$ and separability of $\mathcal{H}$ is note required):

> At this stage assume that inner product and integrals can be exchanged and the validity of Fubini formula. Then for $\mu,\nu$ in $M$, 
>   \begin{align}
> \langle I_\mu, I_\nu\rangle = \int \left( \int K(s,t) d\nu(s)\right) d\mu(t) = \int K d(\mu \otimes \nu)
> \end{align}

I am interested in the conditions on $K$ such that

1. inner product and integrals can be exchanged
2. Fubini's formula is valid

Is it sufficient that $K$ is bounded and measurable? I think a key is the separability if $\mathcal{H}$.

**Edit:**

A Google books preview can be found [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=bX3TBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP11&ots=jU0jS35vF3&dq=reproducing%20kernel%20space%20emedding%20metrics%20on%20probability&lr&pg=PP8#v=onepage&q&f=false) and I think I am allowed to quote some theorems if requested. [Here](https://books.google.de/books?id=RWU8R2Ew3AcC&lpg=PA153&ots=QoGY5WytcE&dq=fubini&lr&pg=PA153#v=onepage&q&f=false) a shorter article with similar content at page 153.